# Getting the view names from the List View dropdown

Tags: list-view

In our org lot of people are creating custom list views and then deleting them.

As admin we wanted the list view names displayed under the Views drop down.

Are these names stored in any object which we can query. Can anyone provide any suggestions to query and retrieve the list view names for a specific object.

Comment: Please look into this link.It might help you https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000096ONIAY

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no way to query this information using **SOQL** or via **Platform Reports**.

However you can use some **Apex code** or the **Metadata API** (again call via code). For example you could run the following from **Developer Console** to dump the List View names to the Debug log.

```
ApexPages.StandardSetController controller = 
    new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator('select Id from Account Limit 1'));
List<System.SelectOption> listViews = controller.getListViewOptions();
for(System.SelectOption listView : listViews)
{
    System.debug('List View Name : ' + listView.getValue());
    System.debug('List View Label : ' + listView.getLabel());
}
```

Gives the following...

> 18:19:50.134 (134639872)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|List View Name : 00BG000000702tHMAQ
>
> 18:19:50.134 (134705838)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|List View Label : New This Week
>
> 18:19:50.134 (134760958)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|List View Name : 00BG000000702tSMAQ
>
> 18:19:50.134 (134785511)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|List View Label : New Last Week
>
> 18:19:50.134 (134835719)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|List View Name : 00BG000000702tjMAA
>
> 18:19:50.134 (134860314)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|List View Label : Platinum and Gold SLA Customers
>
> 18:19:50.134 (134907861)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|List View Name : 00BG000000702trMAA
>
> 18:19:50.134 (134931455)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|List View Label : Recently Viewed Accounts
>
> 18:19:50.134 (134980144)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|List View Name : 00BG000000702tsMAA
>
> 18:19:50.135 (135008341)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|List View Label : All Accounts
>
> 18:19:50.135 (135057102)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|List View Name : 00BG000000702u0MAA
>
> 18:19:50.135 (135079985)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|List View Label : My Accounts

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. It helped a Great Deal!!!

Comment: Make sure you construct the StandardSetController with a query locator if you are running this as anonymous apex. I tried using a list as a constructor and got the error message: `UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: No Visualforce context has been established!`